# Proper passport strategy for anonymous mobile application

Tags: node.js, authentication, express, token, passport.js

I'm building an anonymous app like yik yak and wanted to ask what is the proper passport strategy to use to authenticate. I'm currently using the device's UUID. I looked at the local strategy and that requires a username, password and it's session based (i'm implementing token based so my api isn't left open).

That said, would I implement a passport-http basic strategy and disregard the password altogether and use just the UUID as authentication?

Please help! I'm not entirely sure how to approach this issue. I do know, however, that I don't want the user to login, ever.

Thanks!

Comment: if you want it to be anonymous, why do you want authentication? Device UUID works fine for keeping track of users

Comment: Because I don't want my API to be open for anyone to access. If I authenticate each user, and add their uuid to the DB, I can make sure that only someone who has downloaded my app is making a request to my API. After registering they'll receive a token that's stored on the client side.

Comment: @Mihado were you able to figure something out? Did you end up going with the UUID approach?

Comment: Did you ever solve this?

Comment: I did. I will post a response tomorrow once back from vacation. @user3344977

Comment: any updates on this?

Comment: Use a JWT token for authorization. That's what I did! @OmarAlHalabi

Comment: @Mihado well noted.If I understand correctly, you signed in by device UUID to generate the token, right?

Comment: @OmarAlHalabi yes. Remember, you need to find a way to persist that token on the client side. I used NSUserDefaults.

Comment: @Mihado alright thank you!